# Use Django context processor or middleware to check for cookies on templates?

Tags: django, templates, cookies, django-templates, django-sessions

My Django app has Post objects. Each Post has an IntegerField that gets incremented whenever a certain link is clicked. When that link is clicked, I set a cookie to indicate that it has been clicked and prevent the user from clicking it again. Thus the cookie will look like so:

`is_clicked=[1,2,3,4,5]`

where the integers 1,2,3,4,5 are Post.id.

Should I do this using context processor, middleware, or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Middleware. Specifically, the [session middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/).